# KnockoutJs applyBindings clearing default values set by Asp.net Webforms

Tags: knockout.js, webforms

I am new to KnockOutJs and developing a page that uses KnockOutJs to maintain Client model state and Asp.Net Webforms.
When I request a page from the server, the controls (like textbox, spans) are already filled by Asp.Net code behind.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" text="John" data-bind="value: firstName" id="txtFirstName"></asp:TextBox>
```

Now in my javascript when I define my viewmodel

```
var viewModel = { userId = ko.observable() }
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

The applyBindings statement causes the value of text box to be reset, as I am not defining my initial value in ko.observable().

Is there an overload for applyBindings that will not apply the model to DOM elements but just binds the model with DOM or does the reverse (i.e. read values from DOM into the model)

Comment: I can't do it now, but I suspect a custom binding is probably the way to go here.  So rather than using the built in `value` binding, you write your own that does the same thing, but with the ability to take it's initial value from the DOM.  I'll take a stab at it tomorrow if no one else has by then.

Comment: Alternatively, wherever your code is that's setting the value of the text box in the code behind, can you alter it so it injects the value into your javascript viewmodel instead?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, Thanks for the direction, I will try this over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use server side code to populate your viewmodel instead of using server side code to populate your textboxes.

```
var viewModel = { firstName = ko.observable('<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(FirstName) %>') };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Or Ideally you would create a model on the server side and serialize it to json using json.net:

```
function ViewModel(model) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable(model.FirstName);
};

var model = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) %>;
var viewModel = new ViewModel(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```